# reHashing a table

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

I am trying to rehash a table by deleting old table and creating a new bigger table with same contents. I created a reHash function, but this function gives memory leaks, causing the program to crash when the function is executed. I can't find my error.

```
void HashMap::reHash()
{
int OldCapacity = cap;
cap = cap * 2 + 1; //set new capacity
Node** newHashTable = new Node*[cap]; //create a temporary table to hold info
for (int i = 0; i < cap; i++)
{
    newHashTable[i] = nullptr;
}

const Node* n;
//fill in the new temp table with old info
for (int i = 0; i < OldCapacity; ++i)
{
    n = HashTable[i];
    while (n != nullptr)
    {
        //initialize new node
        Node* nod = new Node;
        nod->key = n->key;
        nod->value = n->value;
        nod->next = nullptr;
        Node*& bucket = newHashTable[default_hash_function(n->key)/cap];
        nod->next = bucket;
        bucket = nod;
        n = n->next;
    }
}

// delete the links 
for (int i = 0; i < OldCapacity; ++i)
{
    Node *curr = HashTable[i];
    Node *next;
    while (curr != nullptr)
    {
        next = curr->next;
        delete curr;
        curr = next;
    }
}
HashTable = newHashTable;
}
```

Comment: You can always look at the implementation of `std::unordered_map::rehash()` for inspiration. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/rehash/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your fundamental leak is this:

```
HashTable = newHashTable;
```

You never deleted the old pointer-array. It should be this:

```
delete [] HashTable;
HashTable = newHashTable;
```

You also aren't computing the modulo of your hash function correctly for your table size in the reassignment, which would be devastating to your hash table.

This:

```
Node*& bucket = newHashTable[default_hash_function(tmp->key) / cap];
```

should be this:

```
Node*& bucket = newHashTable[default_hash_function(tmp->key) % cap];
// note modulo operator -------------------------------------^
```

---

**Rehash Sans-Allocations**

Honestly, *none* of the dynamic allocations are needed in this except allocating the new bed. You can use the existing nodes by moving them from the old bed to the new one.

```
void HashMap::reHash()
{
    int OldCapacity = cap;
    cap = cap * 2 + 1;

    // allocate new bed. note: uses () to value-initialize nullptr entries
    Node** newHashTable = new Node*[cap]();

    //fill in the new temp table with old info
    for (int i = 0; i < OldCapacity; ++i)
    {
        Node *n = HashTable[i];
        while (n != nullptr)
        {
            // advance n *before* moving node to new hash bed
            Node *tmp = n;
            n = n->next;

            // find the proper collision list pointer.
            Node*& bucket = newHashTable[default_hash_function(tmp->key) % cap];
            tmp->next = bucket;
            bucket = tmp;
        }
    }

    delete [] HashTable;
    HashTable = newHashTable;
}
```